# How to return list of objects from controller and display them using JQuery (Spring MVC, ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, spring

First, this is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
   @Autowired
   SqlSession sqlSession;
   @Autowired
   Message messageVO;


@RequestMapping(value="getMessages", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Message> getMessages(HttpSession session){
    JbuserDAO dao = sqlSession.getMapper(JbuserDAO.class);
    List<Message> inboxList = null;
    String logedinUserId = (String) session.getAttribute("loginId");
    inboxList = dao.getInboxList(logedinUserId);
    System.out.println(inboxList);       //I do get the list here so it's not sql problem. I think.
    return inboxList;
}
```

and this is my JQuery:

```
$(function(){
   viewingInbox();
   $("#viewInbox").on('click', function(){
        viewingInbox();
    });
  });


function viewingInbox(){

   $.ajax({
        url: "getMessages"
      , method: "GET"
      , dataType: "JSON"
      , contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      , success: function(obj){
        alert(obj.inboxList);      //I get undefined here
        messageInbox(obj);
      }
  });
}


function messageInbox(obj){
   var list = '<div>';
   $(obj.inboxList).each(function(i, item){
       list = list + '<article class="media">'
                  + '<span class="pull-left"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes"></span>'
                  + '<span class="pull-left thumb-sm"><img src="resources/images/a2.png" alt="..."></span>'
                  + '<div class="media-body">'
                  + '<div class="pull-right media-xs text-center text-muted">'
                  + '<strong class="h4">12:18</strong><br></div>'
                  + '<a href="#" class="h4">123'+item.sendidjbuser+'</a>'
                  + '<small class="block m-t-sm">'+item.message+'</small></div></article>'
   });
      list = list + '</div>';
      alert(list);               //here I get only <div></div>
      $("#inboxDiv").html(list);
      alert("messageInbox end");
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to get saved messages from DB and return them as a list of Message VO I made and then print them out on jsp.
I thought this was the way to do it but I don't think I'm getting the list from the controller. I tried putting alert(message) inside the each statement, and it didn't work; no alert messages. That means I'm not getting the list from the controller. Am I missing something?

I jave json-databind dependency added, but that's everything I have concerning json.

I only learned Strut2 for a month and only recently started using Spring so I must have made stupid mistake I don't know. Please tell me what that is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `obj`  ? did you get correct obj? from controller i think you need to conver it to json or in success callback parse as json

Comment: That should be the returned inboxList from the controller. That's how I used to do on Struts2. I guess on Spring it doesn't work like that. How do I do that parsing in success callback or converting it to json in controller?

Comment: did you try `console.log(obj)` in success callback

Comment: I didn't learn what that is but l'll try that right now

Comment: jQuery.parseJSON()  to parse json in success callback if you receive json success callback

Comment: I got this from console.log(obj) : Array[3]
0
:
Object
message
:
"111"
messageid
:
"kittyhsk@gmail.com20160413143845120"
reportmessageSet
:
Array[0]
requestIdjbuser
:
null
senddate
:
"2016-04-13 14:38:45"
sendidjbuser
:
null
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: is it json which you want?

Comment: Uh, no, as long as I can get the result shown on jsp I'm happy with whatever it would be. Actually, I only started learning all this for a little more than 6 months so I don't know what json really is..

Comment: I know I should learn things first and then do things like this but I'm being rushed by my teachers too.. So I guess there's nothing I can do here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109004/discussion-between-uzaif-and-sunsun).

Comment: Learn to use a debugger instead of relying on console output: both your IDE and your browser have one, it's 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ResponseEntity as return element and can also convert your list to json list so that jquery can interpret it as iterative element.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="getMessages", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getMessages(HttpSession session){
        JbuserDAO dao = sqlSession.getMapper(JbuserDAO.class);
        List<Message> inboxList = null;
        String logedinUserId = (String) session.getAttribute("loginId");
        inboxList = dao.getInboxList(logedinUserId);


  com.google.gson.Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
        String jsonString = gson.toJson(inboxList);
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(jsonString, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED); 


    }
```

This way you will definitely get list of your message as you want. P.S: i haven't gone through your rest of the code. But things like the following should work:

```
success: function(obj){

 $.each(obj, function(index) {
            alert(obj[index].sendidjbuser);
            alert(obj[index].message);
        });


      }
```

Comment: And it did. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Unlike Struts2, I didn't have to do like this:

```
$(obj.inboxList).each(function(i, item){
```

I think in Struts2 I had to put obj.inboxList because on the action side there are getter and setters.

In Spring, there are no getter and setters so maybe, really maybe because I'm just guessing here, that's why just using obj works:

```
$(obj).each(function(i, item){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add Jackson to your classpath or add dependencies to maven and Spring Mvc convert your list to json. You only need add parameter to @RequestMapping produces="application/json", in your case it look @RequestMapping(value="getMessages", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json"), also parameter produces unnecessary but recommended.
And you not need any edit in your controller.